# tiled monitor support ( LG 34wk95u )

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, xrandr, external-monitor

I have an LG 34WK95U monitor that I can't get to function at full 5120x2160@60Hz resolution in Ubuntu. The max I get is 3440x1440@60 or I can manually force 5120x2160@30 with xrandr but it's not possible to select in the normal display settings.

This is a branch of from my previous question [High-res monitor support, 5120x2160, LG 34WK95](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230124/high-res-monitor-support-5120x2160-lg-34wk95) which hasn't yet been resolved.

I started playing around more with `xrandr --prop` which gave me some interesting output indication that display is **tiled**. Its is however only connected over a single thunderbolt 3 port, and it doesn't have dual physical displayport connectors either.

So I started thinking that maybe it expect to be operated as two tiles over the single physical interface somehow, but how can I accomplish that? The tile size is listed as 2560x2160 which is very encouraging since that is half the full resolution that I actually want.

UPDATE:
Reading online it seems the display should be able to operate using DP1.2 using MST and tiling, or DP1.4 using SST without tiling. Using the monitor OSD to switch between DP versions doesn't change the output of xrandr in any way that I can see.

https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/LG-Ultrawide-Monitor-34-inch-5k2k-compatibility/m-p/7433664/highlight/true#M38557

https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/success-gigabyte-designare-z390-thunderbolt-3-i7-9700k-amd-rx-580.267551/page-679#post-1994071

```bsh
$ xrandr --prop
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3440 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff004d10ba1400000000
        161d0104a52213780ede50a3544c9926
        0f505400000001010101010101010101
        010101010101ac3780a070383e403020
        350058c2100000180000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000fe004d
        57503154804c513135364d3100000000
        0002410332001200000a010a202000d3
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 86 
        supported: 86
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
   1920x1080     60.00 +  59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 connected primary 3440x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 800mm x 330mm
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff001e6d2177d3ad0200
        091d0104b55021789e09c1ae5044af26
        0e50542108007140818081c0a9c0d1c0
        810001010101e77c70a0d0a029503020
        3a00204a3100001a9d6770a0d0a02250
        30203a00204a3100001a000000fd0030
        3d1e874c000a202020202020000000fc
        004c472048445220354b0a202020033d
        02031971449004030123090707830100
        00e305c000e30605014dd000a0f0703e
        803020650c204a3100001a286800a0f0
        703e800890650c204a3100001a000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        000000000000000000000000000000e3
        701279030001000c401fe40c00147008
        90788999030014e07c00086f0d9f002f
        801f009f052800020009000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000002590
        701279030012001682100000ff096f08
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 92 
        supported: 92
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
   3440x1440     59.97*+  59.96    49.99  
   3840x2160     60.00    30.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    59.94  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      59.97  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
DP-2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff001e6d2177d3ad0200
        091d0104b55021789e09c1ae5044af26
        0e505420000001010101010101010101
        01010101010100000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000fd0030
        3d1e874c000a202020202020000000fc
        004c472048445220354b0a202020017a
        701279030001000c401fe40c00147008
        9078899912001680101000ff096f0800
        0000000047534d217701010101030014
        f0890008ff094f0007801f006f085100
        00000700000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000003290
    TILE: 1 1 2 1 1 0 2560 2160 
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 100 
        supported: 100
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
   2560x2160     59.66  
   640x480       59.94  
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 106 
        supported: 106
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
```

Here is the output of `lspci` showing the hardware on the laptop side of things, I'm running using the nvidia card at the moment, but the display info looks the same if I switch to the Intel card and reboot.

```bsh
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e20 (rev 0d)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 0d)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0d)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30e (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117GLM [Quadro T2000 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
03:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
03:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
04:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge DD 2018] (rev 06)
06:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge DD 2018] (rev 06)
07:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
3a:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 USB 3.1 Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
3b:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29)
3c:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
3d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix Device 1627
```

Comment: How about trying to set both in 2560x2160 60Hz mode ?

Comment: I tried doing 

```xrandr --addmode DP-1-1 2560x2160
xrandr --addmode DP-1-2 2560x2160
# Combine our two outputs into one big monitor
xrandr --screen 0 --setmonitor LG34WK95U 5120/800x2160/330+0+0 DP-1-1,DP-1-2 
xrandr --output DP-1-1 --mode 2560x2160 --pos 0x0
xrandr --output DP-1-2 --mode 2560x2160 --pos 2560x0
```

Gave me a very weird malformed display, it hard the correct resolution but parts of the picture ended up in the wrong place and the was a lot of interference anmd flickering going on.

Comment: I never seen `--setmonitor` option. I'm blind here, I haven't tested/used a double lane monitor before. One question: Are you the one added that `2560x2160 59.66` mode in 2nd tile? It is not available in the 1st? You may try putting  same lower freq mode for both `2560x2160 59.66` or   `2560x2160 30.00` just for testing, and for interference put 2px in between so 2nd tile `--pos 2562x0`.

Comment: The 2560x2160 59.66 is the automatically in the second tile, but not in the first. I'm wondering if that is somehow the problem? I don't know how tiled resolutions are supposed to look?

Comment: ```---setmonitor``` is apparently fairly and used for this type of scenario

Comment: I tried forcing 2560x2160@30 without success for both outputs without any success.

Comment: I filed a bug report, got a response to wait for a newer version of mutter. Does that even make since when I can't physically set the correct resolution?
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1876706

Comment: It may take long, I would recommend trying another distribution live CD that contains gnome-3.36.2 , you may search on https://distrowatch.com/  example: Manjaro has it. At least you can check without loosing time waiting for an uncertain update.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately the manjaro live CD still used mutter 3.36.1, I tried installing manjaro XFCE instead, which was interesting in that it actually displayed both outputs as seperate screens in the UI. I could set the second output to 2560x2160 as before, and by adding that mode to the first output as well I could bring up the screen in 5120x2160, but it was still malformed. The first input was repeated across four sections of the screen, repeating itself and also having slight tearing and movement of the image across the screen. So the input wasn't what the screen expected.

Comment: Running just the first ouput in 2560x2160 works in the sense that it gives me that image centered on the screen, so the output on the second output does make a difference in that it makes the screen try to show something over the entire panel.

Comment: I'm trying on the latest Pop_OS which has 3.36.2, with no luck. I tried the same thing you did above and got the same result.

Comment: I found this bugreport which I think is related, will try using some of the scripts provided in there.
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed in Linux 5.9rc1, at least for Intel graphics cards.
For more details see here
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/27

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by copying the specific mode from macOS with SwitchResX. It did not require using both DisplayPorts with xrandr for me. I've got DisplayPort 1.2 selected in my OSD.

Use xrandr to find the first output for the monitor and put that below in place of `DisplayPort-2`

```
xrandr --newmode "5120x2160" 703.75 5120 5168 5200 5280 2160 2163 2173 2222 +HSync -VSync
xrandr --addmode DisplayPort-2 5120x2160
xrandr --output DisplayPort-2 --mode 5120x2160
```

Comment: I tried this yesterday, I'm also on a 5.4.0 kernel, but gnome 3.36.1. Tried a pop os live environment from a usb stick since you mentioend in another comment that you used that, but that also contained the old version. Unfortunately it didn't work, when setting the output mode I get ` xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed` Which graphic card do you have? I have both a nvidia and Intel I can switch between (nVidia PRIME) , but I get the same error for both. But from what I gather the error above is that the card can't handle the mode. So most likely not related to gnome versions.